# Validate a form field only if populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a field in a form which is optional but if it is completed I want to validate that it is an integer value. In my model I have:

```
validates :number_of_employees, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

This works but when I submit the form with the value not completed it raises an error because it is not numeric. I gather you can put and if condition in the validates statement but not sure if this is the correct way to handle this or what the syntax is to check for existance.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an `:if` option, the idiomatic way to allow empt fields to pass validation is to use the [`:allow_blank`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_blank) option. It's common to all the validators except the `presence` validator.

```
validates :number_of_employees, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_blank: true }
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks. I'd missed that in the documentation. It works perfectly.